# Do I have a chance to know when my App is about to be killed by System when memory is low?

Tags: android

I do some initialization work(such as open DB or init disc cache for image) at Application.onCreate or MainActivity.onCreate, but there is no chance for us to do uninitlization work(such as close DB or flush/close/uninit disc cache for image) when App is about to be killed by system.

We all know Application.onDestroy is only invoked on emulator......
Application.onLowMemory will never be called when my App is killed by system when memory is low.

Anybody can do me a fovour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look through [the Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), it should tell you where you can do this. To summarise it

You should assume that your app can be killed anytime after `onPause()` is called -- so any un-initilization that you want to do should be done in `onPause()`

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this, but this is the most correct way. All other methods do not work reliably and Google has made it clear that Android apps can and will be killed without any notification by the system.

Answer (score 1):

[onTrimMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) is the place where you should think seriously about releasing some of your resources. That is for API14. onLowMemory() is your best bet for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

[OutOfMemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) is derived from [Error](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html) class. And, from its documentation,

```
Error is the superclass of all classes that represent unrecoverable errors.
 When errors are thrown, they should not be caught by application code.
```

So the simple answer is No.

So whats the alternative?

You can constantly monitor your heap usages and before getting low memory error and do what ever things you wanna do.